# What is the correct way to request a tag alias?

Tags: feature-request, support

On StackOverflow I tried to post with the tag 'drupal7', which was immediately squashed with a bold red warning telling me I can't create tags because I don't have the reputation for it. I added the tag I intended, 'drupal-7', but is there a way I can ask for 'drupal7' to be treated as an alias of 'drupal-7'?

Comment: Perhaps more generally, I fear some obscure ambiguity, but could the system be modified to treat tags as equivalent modulo hyphenization, so if you enter a tag that with hyphens stripped out it equals some existing tag, your hyphenization is treated as an alias of the existing official hyphenization?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't. We don't create tag synonyms that only differ by one or more hyphens anymore, for a couple reasons:

1. The tag suggestions that appear directly below ignore hyphens and will always show you the hyphenated (or non-hyphenated) version of the tag as a suggestion. All you have to do is click on it.
2. It spams our system with useless different hyphenated versions of a tag. For something that has more than two words, users were suggesting every possible hyphenated version. So for something like [sql-server-2000](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2000), we ended up with synonyms like [sqlserver-2000](/questions/tagged/sqlserver-2000), [sql-server2000](/questions/tagged/sql-server2000), and [sqlserver2000](/questions/tagged/sqlserver2000) (these tag synonyms *actually* existed). These synonyms waste space and achieve nothing in the long-run.

As well, a tag must actually exist in the system before a user can even suggest it as a synonym of another tag (moderators exempt). So even if you had proper privileges, you couldn't suggest a non-hyphenated tag as a synonym of a hyphenated one, since the system also forbids the creation of new tags which only differ by one or more hyphens.

---

**As for your comment:**

> Perhaps more generally, I fear some obscure ambiguity, but could the system be modified to treat tags as equivalent modulo hyphenization, so if you enter a tag that with hyphens stripped out it equals some existing tag, your hyphenization is treated as an alias of the existing official hyphenization?

I actually agree with this, and think it would make a good feature request*. Since tag creation cannot occur any longer for things that only differ by hyphens, it makes sense that when attempting to post a question, the system ignored all hyphens for the purpose of finding an appropriate tag. This would make it easier on those who, for example, type in "drupal7" and confirm the tag by hitting space without clicking on the proper [drupal-7](/questions/tagged/drupal-7) tag when it appears in the tag suggestions.

* This would, however, first require cleaning up *all* the still existing tags that differ from another tag by only hyphens. Otherwise it might cause some problems.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I propose or vote on tag synonyms?
>
> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or
>   more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer
>   score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag,
>   can vote for tag synonyms.

The full details are [here in the Help section on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)

I can't see you qualify for this with the drupal tags. I suggest answering more questions with that tag. Earning more reputation and when you reach 2500, make the suggestion, or as you've done here, it will bring attention to it.